# datetme, timestamp fields in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I need confirmation that this is correct. My requirement is all tables require 3 colunms:
1) Date row is created
2) Date row is last updated
3) Flag if the row is active or not.

So I have these 3 colunms in every table
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

I assume I do not have to do anything else, these columns can take care of themselves right? is_active will always default to 1 when the table is created, so i do not have to touch anything (just need to make those values to 0 manually later if i want to show a row as not active). Datetime will always auto set the current date & time the row is created on its own,i assume? And timestamp will auto update when the row is updated.

Am i missing something that i need to add like trigger or anything or is this good?

Comment: i think is good, you cover all the requirements

Answer (score 1):

Nothing that you posted indicates that the `created` datetime column will be automatically set.  It has no default - you will need to provide a value for it.

You could make it a timestamp and give it the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, but then you run into another issue - according to the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html), you can only use the magical DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP flags on the *first* TIMESTAMP column in a table.

You can either provide a value for that column yourself when you insert, such as NOW(), or you could set up a trigger to happen on insert into that table that would set it for you.

Comment: Well the whole point is to automate these columns so no one has to explicitly specify a date/time. The less work to do the better. I guess triggers may slow the table down if the DB has to wait and before inserting records esp on largee tables so Now() seems a better bet to use? I need to change it to: created datetime Now() NOT NULL ?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can not set functions such as NOW() to be the default value for a column.  `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the case of `timestamp` columns is a special magical exception.  A trigger would add negligible time to your inserts - you should probably set up a `CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE INSERT ...`